# Pass field handle from to render tag using Freeform field

Tags: plugin-freeform

I'm new to Craft and I'm trying to figure out how to place a form within an entry using a Solspace Freeform field.  Specifically I need to pass the form handle into the render tag to place that form on a particular page.

```
{{ craft.freeform.form("formHandlefromfreeformfield").render() }}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [this](https://solspace.com/craft/freeform/docs/fieldtypes/#templates) what you are looking for?

```
{{ entry.myFreeformfieldname.render() }}
```

Comment: Thanks! I believe you need to use the craft.freeform.form tag to display the form but my question was what is the syntax to pass the form handle to that tag?

Comment: You don't need that, `entry.fieldHandle` contains the form object which has the render method. The render tag grabs the form by handle and executes the render method so its basically the same but if you want to use it that way for whatever reason have a look at the documentation. `entry.fieldHandle.handle` contains the handle of the form

Comment: Ok, thanks.  That one hasn't worked for me.  Anyway, so what is the syntax for passing the formhandle to that tag ie how do I get the formhandle into`{{ entry.myFreeformfieldname.render() }}`

Comment: I stated it multiple times, it's all in the link I provided `entry.fieldHandle.handle` will return the form handle and you can render it with `craft.freeform.form(entry.fieldHandle.handle).render()` of course you need to insert a form in your cp and you have to replace the `fieldHandle` with the correct handle of your relationfield (I hope you did that) Anyway - if it does not work, could you `dump` your field? And tell if it is an instance of `freeForm`

Comment: Finally got it working.  This is what I needed`{{ craft.freeform.form(block.form.handle).render() }}` Thank you for your help!

Comment: Of course if your form is in an matrix element you need to use that block instead of an entry. We can't read your mind and if you don't show us your code nor your fields or your structure we can't know you did it that way. Glad you made it, next time you should provide more information otherwise we can only provide basic help. With this in mind: `block.form.render()` is a much better approach since you'll fetch the form twice currently